# Entity Framework side effects of converting IEnumerable to IQueryable

Tags: c#, entity-framework

This is not a question about How To Convert.  This is a question about side-effects.  Let's begin with my understanding that:

- IQueryable is a deferred collection in the process of generating SQL.
- IEnumerable is a deferred collection and can filter SQL results, but SQL generation is already complete.
- T or List is concrete and cannot generate or filter SQL at the database

So we typically start with IQueryables, and Where extensions are generating SQL.

We then move into IEnumerables, the query is still deferred, but I can apply what in-code filtering I wish to add.  The Query will still return all results from the IQueryable filters, but the Enumerable will only return code-filtered results.

When the Queryable or Enumerable is executed with a concrete call like ToList, Single, First, etc... then I am left with Concrete object(s).

So if I take a Queryable, convert it to an Enumerable, can I then change it back to a Queryable?  Under what circumstances?  What if I chain filters to the IEnumerable first?  Pseudocode Example:

```
var yesterdaysTacoOrders = GetOrdersForDate(yesterday);

public List<Order> GetOrdersForDate(DateTime someDate) 
{
    using (var context = new DbContext()) 
    {
        return GetOrderQuery(context, someDate)
                .Where(x => x.OrderType == OrderType.Retail).ToList();
    }
}

public IQueryable<Order> GetOrderQuery(DbContext context, DateTime someDate) 
{
    return GetOrderEnumerable(context, someDate)
            .Where(x => x.OrderName.Contains("Taco")).AsQueryable();
}

public IEnumerable<Order> GetOrderEnumerable(DbContext context, DateTime someDate) 
{
    return context.Set<Order>()
            .Where(x => x.Date == someDate).AsEnumerable();
}
```

The first code to actually execute is the last line above where an Entity Framework Context is used to pull an IQueryable, but returns an IEnumerable.

Its Caller (GetOrderQuery) receives the IEnumerable, applies a filter, but returns an IQueryable.

ITS CALLER (GetOrdersForDate) receives the IQueryable, applies a filter, and executes with a ToList().

What parts are transformed into SQL, and what parts are filtered In-Code?  What are the Side-Effects?

Comment: Take a look at this blog post for a decent explanation https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/entity-framework-core-and-linq-to-entities-5-query-translation-implementation

Comment: Can you not use `.AsQueryable` from the `System.Linq` extension methods? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353734(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Eris Maybe I'm not clear, but the question isn't `How do you convert from IEnumerable to IQueryable`.  It is a question about the side effects of doing so, if any.

Comment: You misunderstand something. IQueryable<T> INHERITS IEnumerable<T>, so there are no side effects specific to EF. If the IEnumerable was indeed an IQueryable (or something that derives from it), the resulting IQueryable will continue to gather query information and compute the query when it is enumerated. If the IEnumerable was something else (if it is conversable at all), it is merely a collection, so the query is computed and executed already, the conversion has no effect (other than the type change).

Comment: How much do you know about extension methods? Because I think its important to understand that LINQ provides different overloads of extension methods for the compile time types `IEnumerable<T>` and `IQueryable<T>`. So before going into detail of what happens inside, you should first understand that you really call different methods depending on the compile time type, even if the actual runtime type is the same.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro That does not provide an EF `IQueryable`, the one returned by `AsQueryable()` actually doesn't implement things like `IAsyncEnumerable`. While the runtime EF `IQueryable` flavor does